# How to use index number with PageFactory.initElement(driver, this) to identify two identical elements from the DOM?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

On a webpage, we are having two links displayed with no other attribute than the link text. I want to make a page object class for a page.

Here the question is how I can specify the `WebElement` object declaration in page object class which uniquely identified the second instance of the links displayed.

```
<html>
  <a href="a.html">Link</a>
  <a href="a.html">Link</a>
</html>
```

for the above (just an example to get the idea), I want to get `WebElement` object for the second link using `PageFactory.initElement(driver, this)` statement

```
@FindBy(how = How.LINK_TEXT, using = "Link")
public static WebElement link;
```

I think the above will identify the first object only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are locating a single element selenium will return the first matching element in the DOM. You can specify index if you use `XPATH`

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//a[.='Link'][2]")
public static WebElement link;
```

You can also locate all the links and use index on the returned list

```
@FindBy(how = How.LINK_TEXT, using = "Link")
public static List<WebElement> links;

WebElement link = links.get(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can uniquely identify second element with below `Xpath`.

```
"(//a[.='Link'])[2]"
```

**OR**

```
"(//a[.='Link'])[last()]"   //work if you have 2 Link with innerText ‘Link’
```

**With href attribute**

```
"(//a[@href='a.html'])[2]"
```

**OR**

```
"(//a[@href='a.html'])[last()]"   // work if you have 2 Link with same href
```

Answer (score 0):

Two elements with the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) can't be identical. They may appear with respect to the similar set of attributes but their position within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) whill differ.

Presuming, the `<html>` node being the immediate ancestor of the child `<a>` nodes, to identify the *WebElement* with the second link using `PageFactory.initElement(driver, this)` and [`FindBy`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/FindBy.html) annotation you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  @FindBy(id = "html a:nth-of-type(2)")
  public static WebElement link;
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//html//following::a[2]")
  public static WebElement link;
  ```